# Compressed SortedSet<Long> implementation

Tags: java, bitset, sortedset, run-length-encoding

I need to store a large number of `Long` values in a `SortedSet` implementation in a space-efficient manner.  I was considering bit-set implementations and discovered [Javaewah](http://code.google.com/p/javaewah/).  However, the API expects `int` values rather than `long`s.

Can anyone recommend any alternatives or suggest a good way to solve this problem?  I am mainly concerned with space efficiency.  Upon building the set I will need to access the minimum and maximum element once.  However, access time is not a huge concern (i.e. so a fully run-length encoded implementation will be fine).

**EDIT**

I should be clear that the implementation **does not have to** implement the `SortedSet` interface providing I can access the minimum and maximum elements of the collection.

Comment: Do you need to store the longs only to find the min and max?

Comment: Yes, but I may remove elements from the set as I build it, hence why I need to store every element.

Comment: What is "a large number of long values"?

Comment: Are your values completely random or do they cluster?

Comment: A "large number of values" == 50-100 million, and they do tend to cluster into contiguous sequences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use TLongArrayList which uses a `long[]` underneath.  It supports `sort()` so the min and max will be the first and last value.

Or you could use a `long[]` with a length and do this yourself. ;)

This will use about 64 byte more than the raw values themselves.  You can get more compact if you can make some assumptions about the range of long values. e.g. if they are actually limited to 48-bit.

You might consider using LongBuffer.  If it is memory mapped it avoids using heap or direct memory, but you would have implement a sort routine yourself.

---

If they are clustered, you might be able to represent the data as a Set of ranges.  The ranges could be a pure A - B, or a BitSet with a starting value.  The later works well for phone numbers. ;)

Comment: That class is from Trove. I wonder which one is more efficient, Trove or Apache primitives.

Comment: In terms of memory efficiency, any difference is likely to be in how it grows the array. i.e. how much of the long[] will be unused.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it has Set or how efficient it is compared to regular JCF, but take a look at this:

http://commons.apache.org/primitives/